# PL/SQL: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type. Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a 'person' table with two fields 'person_name' and 'person_age'.

i want write a procedure that return sys_refcursor but calculating a extra field 'is_old'. por example:

```
PROCEDURE people_load(p_name IN VARCHAR2, P_RESULT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE
      isOld BOOLEAN := false;
      CURSOR cursorTemp IS SELECT person_name, person_age, is_old
                           WHERE person_name = p_name;
      BEGIN
          FOR _p IN cursorTemp
          LOOP
            IF _p.person_age > 75 THEN         
              _p.is_old:=TRUE;
            END IF;  
          END LOOP;          
            ¿¿P_RESULT:=cursorTemp; //open P_RESULT for (open cursorTemp);??
        END;
     END people_load;
```

i dont know how to assign temporal cursor 'cursorTemp' to OUT param 'P_RESULT' to returning the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can not use a `BOOLEAN` in SQL, only in PL/SQL.
2. You can not loop through a cursor and recalculate a column.
3. You declare a variable isOld and never use it.

I suggest you calculate the is_old within the cursor. I changed it to contain 1 (true) or 0 (false).

```
  PROCEDURE people_load(p_name IN VARCHAR2, P_RESULT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE
      CURSOR cursorTemp IS SELECT person_name, person_age, case when person_age > 75 then 1 else 0 end is_old
                           WHERE person_name = p_name;
      BEGIN
            P_RESULT := cursorTemp; //open P_RESULT for (open cursorTemp);
        END;
     END people_load;
```

Comment: I wasted 7 hours of my life on this ... if I knew where you live go to your house to clean your shoes.

Comment: It would be a better learning experience if you invested 7 hours learning Oracle through samples. Still you have more time learn. Good Luck :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your advices ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should do the calculation in the select.

```
 CURSOR cursorTemp IS
    SELECT
      person_name,
      person_age,
      CASE WHEN person_age>75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_old
    WHERE person_name = p_name;
```